# reCAPTCHA V3 ASP.NET Framework implementation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

Does anyone have a sample code of reCAPTCHA v3 in ASP.NET ?

I want to create a new ASP.NET project with reCAPTCHA V3 and I can't implement in my  project.

If you can implement reCAPTCHA, please answer this question.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to register your reCAPTCHA V3 and get the keys (siteKey and secretKey).

With the keys in hand, you need to load the follows javascript:

```
<script src="https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api.js?render=reCAPTCHA_site_key"></script>
```

Call grecaptcha.execute on an action or when the page loads

```
    <script>
  grecaptcha.ready(function() {
      grecaptcha.execute('reCAPTCHA_site_key', {action: 'homepage'}).then(function(token) {
         ...
      });
  });
  </script>
```

The grecaptcha.execute with return a token, so you need to send the token to your backend with the request to verify the reCAPTCHA. (https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/verify)

Be careful with the follow token restrictions

> Each reCAPTCHA user response token is valid for two minutes, and can only be verified once to prevent replay attacks. If you need a new token, you can re-run the reCAPTCHA verification.
>
> After you get the response token, you need to verify it within two
>   minutes with reCAPTCHA using the following API to ensure the token is
>   valid.